# Is there a way to create a marker with a label aside of it on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps

I'm using google_maps_flutter to create a map and I'd like to have markers with labels on it's side without having to click on it, just like the real Google Maps
no it's just a marker with an infowindow, but I want a label with the marker title or something outside the marker like

[image]

And then, when you click on the marker it would display the infowindow

I tried changing the elementType labels on the map_style.json, but it didn't work, I don't want to use the label_marker because I think it's weird looking, but if its the only option so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps take a bitmap as marker in Flutter, you can use [widgets_to_image](https://pub.dev/packages/widgets_to_image) package to convert any widget you like into an image, turn it into a bitmap and use it as a marker!